# How to update multiple mysql database rows with same field names?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to update multiple rows that all share the same field names.

The structure is like:

```
+---+-------+--------+
|id | name  | value  |
+---+-------+--------+
| 1 | color | red    |
| 2 | fruit | apple  |
| 3 | day   | friday |
+---+-------+--------+
```

So, something like :

```
$config_data = "UPDATE system_config SET color = '$_POST[color]', fruit = '$_POST[fruit]', day = '$_POST[day]'";

$success = mysql_query($config_data);
```

... will not work. How would I perform this query?

Comment: For posterity: Do `"UPDATE system_config SET color = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[color])."', etc...` Also *validate* the input first.

Comment: This is essentially an unworkable design. EAV tables are the worst for querying and performance. I would design my tables correctly in a normalized fashionwith the fields you need.

Comment: I dont get it... the options table for a wordpress blog has over 150 entries structured like this, but everyone asks why I'm doing it this way and says nobody does it like that. What am I doing wrong? If I have 100 config options, what's the best way of storing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$config_data = "UPDATE system_config SET value = '$_POST[color]' WHERE name = 'color';";
$success = mysql_query($config_data);
$config_data = "UPDATE system_config SET value = '$_POST[fruit]' WHERE name = 'fruit';";
$success = mysql_query($config_data);
$config_data = "UPDATE system_config SET value = '$_POST[day]' WHERE name = 'day'";
$success = mysql_query($config_data);
```

instead.It's necessary to put in more queries in this case

Comment: Man, I was trying to get it all in one query. I have 15-20 values to be updated in one form post.

Comment: @user971230: *Now* you tell us. Edit your question to reflect all relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

You may not do it in only one query.

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

http://cl.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

If you want to make multiple queries "all at once" you could use `mysqli_multi_query`

more documentation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Answer (score 0):

```
update system_config
set value =
case 
when name = 'color' then 'something1'
when name = 'fruit' then 'something2'
when name = 'day' then 'something3'
else value
end
```

Comment: As written, this is overwriting the config NAME not the config VALUE. I tried when name = 'language' then value = '$_POST[language]', but it's not working.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Misunderstood. Edited my answer.

Comment: I'm putting the post value where you have 'something1' etc. What am I doing wrong? `when name = 'language' then '$_POST[language]'`. Your suggestion looks great, it's just not updating anything.

Comment: Try to see how php solves your variables. The syntax is the one I wrote to you.

Comment: remember to sanitize your data!! `$language = filter_var($_POST['language'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` And then, in the query `when name = 'language' then '{$language}'`